# Node Async/Await Recursive Function ends code execution

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have an issue with Node Async Await and recursive functions. For some reason, the code execution stops after resolving the Promise for a recursive function. Below is just a simple example I put in to demonstrate my issue (though found the problem while sending some requests with requests library).

If you run the code, you will see

```
Starting
Inside Promise
```

but not "Test Completed".

```
function promiseFunc(number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (number == 100) {
            console.log('Inside Promise');
            resolve('Done');
        } else {
            number += 1
            promiseFunc(number);
        }
    })
}


(async function testFunc() {
    console.log('Starting');
    await promiseFunc(0)
    console.log("Test completed");
})()
```

Could someone please advise what is the issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A `new Promise()` runs 101 times, a `resolve()` runs once. See the problem?

Comment: Hmm..makes sense. Would you be able to help me convert my example to a right approach? Or at least point me to the right direction?

Comment: I do recommend you to read this article [Promise Antipatterns](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) You are probably having "The Collection Kerfuffle" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ways to fix it:

```
function promiseFunc(number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (number == 100) {
            console.log('Inside Promise');
            resolve('Done');
        } else {
            number += 1;
            resolve(promiseFunc(number));
        }
    })
}


(async function testFunc() {
    console.log('Starting');
    await promiseFunc(0)
    console.log("Test completed");
})()
```

Or, interestingly enough, the equivalent code that uses `async`/`await` instead of explicit `new Promise(...)`, works for your case:

```
// an async function returns a Promise
async function promiseFunc(number) {
        if (number == 100) {
            console.log('Inside Promise');
            return 'Done';
        } else {
            number += 1;
            // it seems to work as intended without saying return promiseFunc(...)
            promiseFunc(number);
        }
    }


(async function testFunc() {
    console.log('Starting');
    await promiseFunc(0)
    console.log("Test completed");
})()
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to do like this

```
  function promiseFunc(number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.post('/api')
        .then((data) => {
            resolve(data);
        })
    })
}

    (async function testFunc() {
    console.log('Starting');
    const result = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
        result[index] = await promiseFunc(0);
    }
    console.log("Test completed");
})()
```

Comment: This was just an example to show my issue. The real life scenario I have is where I make an API call multiple times to wait for the needed response from the API, and then use the response further in the code.

Comment: Updated answer accoding to your requirement